# Good alternative for JAXBContext to use in Android?

Tags: android, xml, web-services, jaxb, webservice-client

In my Android app, I need to talk to a webserver that expects marshalled objects of complex classes. These custom classes were produces from a WSDL file, so they already come with annotations. The server uses JAXB for marhalling and unmarhalling.

So, on the client side, using JAXB, I would simple to this:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("schema_definition_path");
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
```

...and then use the Marshaller and Unmarshaller instances to work serialize/deserialize the custom objects.

Since, it's not a great idea to use the heavy-weight JAXB lib in mobile apps, I am looking for an alternative to do what JAXB does for me here.

I checked out [Simple XML Serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php), but that doesn't seem to provide this kind of functionality. I can only give a class to the unmarshaller instead of the schema definition path. Doing this results in an incomplete xml document, containing only the root element.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please? Is this even possible? Should I use a different lib - which one? I am I just misusing SimpleXML?

Comment: As far as I know and I have looked, Simple XML is the only library that will get close to JAXB like functionality on android. I would give it another shot.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I played around with it a little more. I could just copy the custom classes and replace the JAXB with the SimpleXML annotations. That doesn't seem like a good solution and it will require a lot of manual changes, since the objects are nested pretty deep.
Would it be feasible to copy just the classes needed for the JAXB stuff from the javax.* namespace and repack them?

Comment: So, the question really is, which solution is less ugly ;-)

Comment: Yes it will require a number of manual changes but it only needs to be done once. Or you could write a JAXB to Simple XML converter. But that would probably take longer...as for the copying of the required javax.* namespace code. Maybe. I have not given it a try but it is possible that it could work. It may be more work though than just converting the XML Annotations but if you tried it then I would be very interested to see your results.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into this some more and post a solution once I have one.

Comment: Alright, I failed in moving the JAXB stuff a new package - I moved around a lot of classes, but got stuck at some point. 

Unfortunately, I cannot go with Simple XML because there are many annotations in JAXB of which there doesn't seem to be an equivalent annotation in Simple XML, so the converter wouldn't help much, either. 
I will post my decision in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any better way (see comments to the original question), I decided to manually convert the Objects using the XML Pull API implementation included in Android.

Here is a short tutorial on how to use it: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

I'm not saying it's a good way, but it's the only thing I can think of that will work and where I don't have to touch the original classes.